# How can I convert string "folder/lower-case-with-dash" to "folderLowerCaseWithDash" (i.e. to camelCase format) using regex?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I'm trying to create a function that converts a string to "camelCase" format. The current version of this function will uppercase the letters following a hyphen `-` and also remove the hyphens.

This is the current function:

```
function camelCase(str) {
  return str.replace(/-([a-z])/g, g => {
    return g[1].toUpperCase()
  })
}
```

The string passed to `str` param may contain single forward slashes `/` and hyphens `-` in addition to the alphabetical chars.

I've tried several different combinations of regex that I thought would work, but I've spent too much time trying to figure this out. How can can I change the regular expression `/-([a-z])/g` to remove forward slashes as well?

```
// CURRENT OUTPUT
console.log(camelCase("folder/lower-case-with-dash"))
// folder/lowerCaseWithDash
```

```
// DESIRED OUTPUT
console.log(camelCase("folder/lower-case-with-dash"))
// folderLowerCaseWithDash
```

I would greatly appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a character set that includes `/` so that both `-` and `/` are matched at the beginning:

```js
function camelCase(str) {
  return str.replace(/[\/-]([a-z])/g, g => {
    return g[1].toUpperCase()
  })
}

console.log(camelCase("folder/lower-case-with-dash"))
```

Comment: Thank you @CertainPerformance! So anything within `[]` is kind of like an array and each character (i.e. the escaped forward slash `/` and `-` in this case) are interchanged?

Comment: Kind of, a character set in a regular expression will match any character in the character set. It's like `(?:\/|-)`